# Debian wheezy can reach local network with packet loss, no access to wider internet

Tags: debian, networking

As in the title. I can ping local networks, but there will be 10 packets in a row that would be lost, and the connection is very slow.
There is no access to anything outside the network, including the default gateway, both when pinging IP and by domain name.

Using the step-by-step analysis [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450650/debian-with-local-access-but-not-internet-access), I can't do anything after step 2. All other devices on the network work perfectly fine using that same ethernet cable.

I suppose the problem is two-fold: why is there packet loss on local network, and why can it not reach the external network? It's an old computer that I am just interacting with recently and seems to have a lot tampered with.

Ip route (eth0 is the one I am using for the web):

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.2
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.97
```

Ip addr - the .97 is static and the .117 was set by dhcp

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:07:32:8f:ec:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.97/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0:0
    inet 192.168.1.117/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:07:32:8f:ec:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global eth1
```

EDIT:
ethtool

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

ethtool -S eth0

```
NIC statistics:
     tx_packets: 1847873
     rx_packets: 8265
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_missed: 0
     align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     unicast: 343
     broadcast: 5915
     multicast: 2007
     tx_aborted: 0
     tx_underrun: 0
```

Comment: what if you reduce to number of IP addresses on `eth0` to one? does it fix any of the issues? side note: that's amazing, what are the chances that your two NICs are `00:07:32:8f:ec:be` and `00:07:32:8f:ec:bf`!

Comment: If I comment out the static IP `192.168.1.97` , the dhcp auto-setup doesn't work at all, so there is no internet connection. Evidently some way the settings are set up rely on the .97 address

Comment: what if you prevent the "DHCP auto-setup" instead of removing the static IP - or, remove one of the IP's manually

Comment: Well then the situation remains the same. The only IP on eth0 is the static `192.168.1.97` with the same limitations as described in my original post.

Comment: what make/model are your NICs? It's still amazing to me that the MAC addresses are different by a single bit

Comment: Ethernet controllers are Realtek Semiconductor. but it's standard on any itx board shipped with 2 ethernet ports the MAC differs only by 1 bit

Comment: Oh OK - never seen it because I guess I've never had a board with 2 onboard NICS :p

Comment: If you boot a more modern Debian "live CD", i.e. one that is not 6 years old, do you have the same issue? Also, what if you use eth1 (with appropriate config changes) instead of eth0

Comment: @JaromandaX it all depends who allocates the addresses. If you have one NIC with two ports they're likely to have consecutive ones. Or two different NICs if the MAC address is decided by the server manufacturer (don't think this ever happens). If you have two different NICs with addresses assigned by the NIC company they're probably not consecutive.

Comment: My suspicion here is a problem related to ethernet (not IP). Please run `ethtool eth0` and `ethtool -S eth0` to get some ethernet information.

Comment: @user253751 - yes, when OP stated these are two onboard NIC's it seemed less of a surprise already

Comment: I ran the ethtool command, do not see anything suspicious (see above). Though on a similar but modern debian system I have Twisted-Pair for port and external transceiver instead of internal

Comment: ethtool looks fine to me also. No more clever ideas from me... you said you tried other devices on the same cable; have you also tried this device with different cables?

Comment: Are you sure there's no IP conflict ?
Did you checked your MTU ?

Comment: @binarym yes there is no IP conflict. I checked via my router

Comment: SOLVED: My router was IP-binding 192.168.1.97 to a different MAC address. Setting it to the MAC address of my eth0 fixed the latency and connectivity issues. thanks @binarym for making me consider an IP conflict for a third time

Comment: In that case, post it as an answer and mark this question as "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a duplicate IP issue - in the IP Bind settings of my router the static IP I was setting my system to was registered to a different MAC address.